how to retry the call again on timeout in okHttp3 and get the response only one time
I am making multiple PUT calls on okHttp3 like a loop, on each call response I'm collecting one ID and putting it in a predefined array(length of 10) then once all indexes are filled with ID I will call one final POST api.
so here if I used some retry loop based on the timeout error I got multiple responses from the call so that the final POST api calls multiple times.
Could you please help me how to get a single response from each outcall even if it retries multiple times?
i have this code in handler class file:
public static void makePutRequest(String url, byte[] data, ResponseCallback callback, int numRetries) throws IOException {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(450, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(450, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(400, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, data);

        for (int i = 0; i <= numRetries; i++) { // Loop for retries

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .put(requestBody)
                    .build();

            int finalI = i;
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (callback != null) {
                            try {
                                callback.onResponse(call, response);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle error
                        if (callback != null && finalI < numRetries) {
                            // Retry only if attempts are left
                            Log.d("TAG", "Retry attempt: " + (finalI + 1));
                            makePutRequest(url, data, callback, numRetries - finalI - 1); // Recursive call for retries
                        } else {
                            if (callback != null) {
                                try {
                                    callback.onFailure(call, new IOException("Unexpected response code: " + response));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    if (callback != null && finalI < numRetries) {
                        // Retry only if attempts are left
                        Log.d("TAG", "Retry attempt: " + (finalI + 1) + " due to timeout");
                        try {
                            makePutRequest(url, data, callback, numRetries - finalI - 1); // Recursive call for retries on timeout
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (callback != null) {
                            try {
                                callback.onFailure(call, e);
                            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


from class im calling the PUT api like this:
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
                String url = data.get(i).toString();
                Log.i(TAG + i , url);
                int finalI = i;
                OkHttpRequest.makePutRequest(url, dataList.get(i), new OkHttpRequest.ResponseCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            String eTg = response.headers().get("ETag");
                            eTags[finalI] = eTg;
                            Log.d("TAG", "Header value: et" +finalI +":  " + eTags[finalI]);
                                WritableArray eventData = Arguments.createArray();
                                for (int j = 0; j < eTags.length; j++) {
                                    if(eTags[j] == null){
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    eventData.pushString(eTags[j]);
                                }
                                if(eventData.size() == eTags.length){
                                    //Final POST api call.....
                                }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", "No header found");
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                },3);
            }

I thought, since the first call gets time out i wont get the response but im getting multiple responses..
